# Get ASCII code for pixel values of an Image In Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am using the following lines of code to get an image :

```
if true
clc;
clear all;
close all;
nMod = 7 ;

%cover image

[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.jpg','Select the Cover Image');
file = fullfile(PathName,FileName);
disp(['User selected : ', file]);
cover = imresize(imread(file),[128 128]);
cover = double(cover);
if ndims(cover) ~= 3
    msgbox('The cover image must be colour');
break;
end
figure;
subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(uint8(cover),[]);
title('Cover image');
```

I wanted to get the ASCII code for the various pixel values into an `m * n` array and then print it into the console. Can someone please help me out ? I am new to matlab .. Thanks.

Comment: "Pixels" and "ASCII code" cannot be used in the same, coherent, sentence. Please explain further. ("Pixels have nothing to do with ASCII codes" is a coherent sentence, and a correct statement as well.)

Comment: actually, I wanted to encrypt the image and then subsequently decrypt it. So, I guess this could be done by using the pixel values or ASCII code for the corresponding pixel values.. Thats why I wanted to know as to how to write the code..

Comment: An image is just an array in MATLAB.  cover(1,1,:) is the first pixel.  ASCII values make no sense in this context, since ASCII is a text encoding, and not every byte represents a printable ASCII character.

Comment: okay so how to get the separate pixel values into an array ? I mean value of Red, green and red pixels into 3 separate arrays ?

Comment: They're already in 3 separate arrays if you pass the `if ndims(cover) ~= 3` line.

Comment: cover(:,:,1) is R.  cover(:,:,2) is G.  etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give this a shot. I **think** you're looking for 3 strings, each encoding the numerical data from one of the colors of the image.

As stated in the comments, your question is not very well-formed. But, it's not as far off as some of the comments may indicate. There is no meaningful way to talk about ASCII characters in relation to pixels. There is, however, a lower-level connection to be made. ASCII represented by two-digit hex numbers. "Pixels" in MATLAB are really just a [1x3] array of double-formatted numbers, ranging from 0.0 to 1.0. You can scale those double-formatted numbers up to 256, then encode them as 16-bit integers, which you can then represent as hexadecimal numbers. (Which will, in turn, be representable as ASCII.) Try this:

```
%// First, separate out each color from the main image.
R = cover(:, :, 1);
G = cover(:, :, 2);
B = cover(:, :, 3);

%// Now, perform the transform detailed above.
hexR = dec2hex(int16(R*256));
hexG = dec2hex(int16(G*256));
hexB = dec2hex(int16(B*256));

%// Finally, reshape the color arrays into a single row to form a string.
strHexR = reshape(hexR.', 1, []);    %'//Format 
strHexG = reshape(hexG.', 1, []);    %'//Format 
strHexB = reshape(hexB.', 1, []);    %'//Format 

%// You could stop here, as the data is encoded, but if you want it in ASCII...
%// Translate to ASCII
asciiHexR = char(sscanf(strHexR, ;'%2x')); 
asciiHexG = char(sscanf(strHexG, ;'%2x')); 
asciiHexB = char(sscanf(strHexB, ;'%2x')); 

%// Reshape to a string.
asciiStrHexR = reshape(asciiHexR.', 1, []);    %'//Format 
asciiStrHexG = reshape(asciiHexG.', 1, []);    %'//Format 
asciiStrHexB = reshape(asciiHexB.', 1, []);    %'//Format
```

Enjoy. Let me know if you have any questions.